# creating shortcut to desktop using setup and deployment

Tags: deployment, installation, project

In our application,we are using registry to store some values. we are creating shortcut on desktop for allusers. The thing is when a user log in to my system as another user he can access the shortcut. On clicking the shortcut, the application gets re-install and the registry values are erased. We dont want the registry values to get erased.

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry entries by any chance? This would explain why a repair is triggered when using the shortcut to launch your application.

Please note that per-machine installations (for all users) shouldn't create entries in HKEY_CURRENT_USER. Your installer should use HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE for generic application settings. Your application can then use HKEY_CURRENT_USER to save any user-related data.